# Sum of tensor products as tensor products

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, tensor-products, factoring

We have vectors `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` of the same length *over finite field*. Take the sum of 2 square matrices obtained as tensor products of those vectors.

`a × b + c × d`

Question: do there exist 2 such vectors `e` and `f` so that their tensor product equals that matrix?

`a × b + c × d = e × f`

I know that this is not true generally in numbers. What about finite fields?

Comment: A tensor product of two vectors has rank 1, that should give you some ideas for counterexample.

Comment: Another good exercise: Which tensor products of two vectors form a basis of the tensor product of the two vector spaces?